# spring mail works only while deactivating avast

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

this is my application.properties config for spring mail

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=test@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxxxxxx
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

the mail is sent with success only while deactivating my antivirus any real world solution for such problem

Comment: Sounds more like an Avast issue rather than a Spring issue. I guess you need to properly configure your antivirus software to exclude blocking mails sent to `smtp.gmail.com`. Nonetheless, this doesn't feel like a programming issue to me.

Comment: yes thats right thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Open Avast
> 2. Click on 'Settings' (upper right corner of page)
> 3. Click on 'Troubleshooting'
> 4. Click on 'Redirect Settings'
> 5. Clear all the port #'s from each field
> 6. Check 'Ignore Local Communication'
> 7. Click 'OK'
> 8. Close Avast
>
> Problem solved!

Comment: Hello I have this problem today, but in current Avast I can't find "Redirect Settings" . Do you have any update? Thank you